# How to fetch this result with single query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables

- student which contains id, name, course_id
- course which contains id, name

I want to fetch courses that are associated with more than 2 students.

I have tried:

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM course 
 LEFT JOIN student 
        ON student.course_id=course.id 
     WHERE student.course_id>2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses here. Also no need to left join here as you are only interested in the intersection of cases where course have matching students.

```
SELECT
    course.id AS course_id,
    course.name AS course_name,
    COUNT(student.id) AS student_count
FROM course
INNER JOIN student
  ON student.course_id = course.id
GROUP BY course.id
HAVING student_count > 2
```

Another thought on your schema is that you probably should actually consider a third table `students_to_courses` or similar which relates the students to the course if you intend to have a many-to-many relationship.  Your current schema would only allow a student record to only be associated with a single course.

Answer (score 1):

Mike just about beat me to it; I agree with his conclusion also.

```
  SELECT c.id, c.name 
    FROM course c
    JOIN student s
      ON s.course_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
  HAVING COUNT(s.id) > 2;
```